# ¿Cómo agrupar datos?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Debo realizar un reporte de los servicios por mes realizados en el transcurso del año; la tabla que almacena esta información es **Ventas** con los campos: IdDia, IdVenta e IdServicio, relacionado con la tabla **Dia** que tiene los campos: IdDia, FechaDia.

Con la consulta obtengo los servicios realizados y a que meses pertenece, pero no logro agruparlos por mes y servicio:

```
DECLARE @Description AS varchar(400) 
declare @IdDiaIni int
declare @IdDiaFin int
declare @no_mes int

set @IdDiaIni=(select IdDia from Dia where FechaDia='2018/01/01')
set @IdDiaFin=(select max(IdDia) from Dia)

select  cs.IdServicio, cs.IdDia,  (select MONTH(FechaDia) 
from Dia where IdDia=cs.IdDia) as mes  
from ConsultaServicio cs                    
where IdCentro=1 and IdDia between @IdDiaIni and @IdDiaFin
order by mes
```

Por ejemplo, tengo el servicio "X" y deseo saber cuantos servicios de "X" se realizaron en el mes de enero, cuantos en febrero.

Comment: Haz intentado utilizando las cláusula [COUNT](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms175997%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) o [GROUP BY](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms189288(v=sql.90).aspx) o [HAVING](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms173260(v=sql.110).aspx)?  ¿Qué haz intentado?

Answer (score 1):

Como te comentan en la sección de comentarios. Puedes usar clausulas group by, junto con un count. Aunque necesitaras remover el mes.

```
select  cs.IdServicio, count(cs.IdDia)
from ConsultaServicio cs                    
where IdCentro=1 and IdDia between @IdDiaIni and @IdDiaFin
group by cs.IdServicio
```